# ALCATEL IDOL 2 6037k won't connect via USB cable

Tags: usb, connection-issues

My Alcatel Idol 2 running Android 4.2.2 , won't connect to my laptop but it charges. I tried

- Installing "right" drivers on my laptop
- I tried 4 different USB cables and it still doesn't work
- I tried also to connect other phones via those cable and they charge but my Idol 2 won't connect to transfer some files
- I also tried to connect to another 3 laptops (with different windows (7,10) and it won't connect either
- I tried to turn on and off USB debugging. Also looked up for some USB settings and found nothing in mobile closed)
- Safe mode and factory reset didn't help either

I need to flash a new ROM because my mac adress and bluetooth adress got somehow deleted, so I can't download nor send any softwares in it (i don't have enough internet data to download the ROM to my Idol 2, and I can't connect to any hotspot)

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please make your posts readable by proper formatting and correct grammar. I attempted to improve. You can [edit] to  revise